# jQuery loading text file on local server to DIV

Tags: jquery

I want jQuery to periodically load a text file located on my server into a div called `testMonitor`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#testMonitor').everyTime(500, function (i) {
            var file = '/testsite/test_1.0/stream.txt';
            $.get(file, function (data) {
                $('#testMonitor').text(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I navigate to `testsite/test_1.0/stream.txt` in my browser, I see the text file in all its glory so the file is not missing/broken... but my div shows up completely empty. I've browsed through almost all the questions on SO related to loading a txt/html file in JS/jQ but nothing has worked. Any ideas?

EDIT: everyTime derives from the [jQuery timer](http://jquery.offput.ca/every/) plugin. This isn't broken in and of itself, because I have tested the sample code for everyTime in my div and it does indeed behave as expected.

Comment: Do you have firebug installed? Open it up and wait for a get request to be made. Check the console tab to see what the response was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your browser you are accessing url from below

```
testsite/test_1.0/stream.txt
```

in script you are accessing

```
/testsite/test_1.0/stream.txt
```

with the slash in front, just update location into real one and it will work.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, I can also navigate to the txt with the slash in front and the file also appears. That said, removing the slash from the script also doesn't change the result unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, my mistake... that was the issue. I changed the access url to http://testsite/test_1.0/stream.txt and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `everyTime` does, but I would do that in a different way:

```
(function everyTime(){
     var file = '/testsite/test_1.0/stream.txt';
     $.get(file, function (data) {
         $('#testMonitor').text(data);
         setTimeout(everyTime, 500);
     });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the JQuery `.load()` method?

[Link to JQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Yes, using $('#testMonitor').load('testsite/test_1.0/stream.txt'); but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

`everyTime` is a jQuery plugin and not a built in function, so if you're not loading that, that may be your first problem. I would leverage Javascipt's `setTimeout()` function, to check the file again (at a delay) after successfully checking it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var file = '/testsite/test_1.0/stream.txt';
    function readTextFile () {
        $.get(file, function (data) {
            $('#testMonitor').text(data);
            setTimeout('readTextFile',500);
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        readTextFile();
    });
</script>
```