# Loading local text file using jquery on local server powered by a raspberry pi

Tags: jquery

I am a noob using my raspberry pi as a local server to create a few basic webpages to display some data.

I would like to display some text on one of the webpages, and have tried both the jquery load and ajax functions, with no success. I also had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986163/jquery-loading-text-file-on-local-server-to-div), but couldn't get the text file to load onto the webpage. Here's my script adapted from the other example so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Text from file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#testMonitor').everyTime(500, function (i) {
            var file = '192.168.2.100:8000/helloworld.txt'; //IP Address and name of text file
            $.get(file, function (data) {
                $('#testMonitor').text(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help, and apologies if I have broken any rules, as this is my first post.

Ryan.
**Update**
Thanks to those who have helped so far. My code is now

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Text from file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.timers-master/jquery.timers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#testMonitor').everyTime(50s, function (i) {
            var file = 'http://192.168.2.100:8000/helloworld.txt';
            $.get(file, function (data) {
                $('#testMonitor').text(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="testMonitor"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open up the debugging console in your browser ([F12]) and show us the error thrown.

Comment: your "url" misses the `http://` and if your httpd runs on different port than 8000 (or on a different ip at all) you'll run into the cross origin problem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. Adding "http://" at the start of the ip address doesn't help. The error retrieved from the console reads "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).everyTime is not a function".

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I am able to access additional webpages, i.e. ipaddress:8000/example.html, I don't know if this is relevant information?

Comment: Where is your #testMonitor component? If it is not defined in the html, `$(#testMonitor)` has no result.

Comment: Another reason could be that there [is no `everyTime()` function in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/?s=everyTime). Did you forget to load a plugin?

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I have now added a div element to hopefully display the text: "<div id="testMonitor"></div>.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider indeed, I didn't have that plugin installed. I now have the plugin, and am greeted with "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". I will update my original post with the latest script.